# Ignore missing documentation if superclass has documentation

Tags: java, documentation, sonarqube, javadoc, sonarqube-4.5

Is there any way to tell SonarQube not to count an overriding method into the public documented api statistics if the overridden method is documented? SonarQube finds many methods lacking annotation due to the case below.

[image]

I know there is an annotation to ignore certain rules of SonarQube, however we don't want to add code to our project in order to satisfy SonarQube.

Comment: I can't see the picture but is the overriding method correctly annotated `@Override`?

Comment: I will verify that on Monday. The picture shows a graph from SonarQube with Issues and Public documented API, not super necessary.

Comment: @Tunaki the methods are properly annotated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use inherit doc.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
```

Comment: During furthher investigation I stumbled upon an IntelliJ IDEA Inspection rule saying: "Reports any Javadoc comments which contain only the {@inheritDoc} tag. Since Javadoc copies the super class' comment if no comment is present, a comment containing only an {@inheritDoc} adds nothing. "
Is SonarQube not able to detect this behavior?