# IntelliJ - Find undocumented public methods

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc, intellij-15

Using IntelliJ IDEA 15, **how can I find public methods that lack javadoc** and therefore lead to a decrease of the SonarQube metric Public Documented API as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070485/ignore-missing-documentation-if-superclass-has-documentation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IntelliJ has the ability to *Inspect Code*.

#### 1. Adjust inspection settings

In order to identify missing public documentation, firstly enable the issue *Declaration has Javadoc problems*. You do this by opening the IDE Settings and select *Editor -> Inspections*. In the right menu select *Java -> Javadoc issues -> Declaration has Javadoc problems*. Activate this issue.

[image]

Again in the lower right corner you will see some options for this issue. Make sure, that for the tab *Method*, the *Scope* is set to *public*. Also check *Ignore simple property access* as you don't want to be informed of getters and setters lacking documentation.

[image]

Click *OK* to save.

#### 2. Inspect the code

In the top menu bar in IntelliJ open *Analyze -> Inspect Code...*, select how much shall be inspected and run it by clicking on *OK*. In the *Inspection Results* look for *Javadoc issues -> Declaration has Javadoc problems*. Those issues stating *Required Javadoc is absent* are what you are looking for.